# webpack expose-loader not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, webpack

In my webpack config I have the following line to expose jQuery on the global scope

```
{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery' },
```

I have a file that uses the $. For example:

```
.getScript(`${url}/scripts/test.js`)
    .done(() => {
       document.querySelector('#trustlogo_ph').innerHtml($.trustlogo(`${url}/content/themes/images/trustlogo.png`, 'SC4', 'none'));
    });
```

However, during my webpack build, get the following error:

```
error  '$' is not defined  no-undef
```

Also, if I put the following directly in my file:

```
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');
```

I get this error:

```
error  Unable to resolve path to module 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery'  import/no-unresolved
```

According to this page, the above should all work: https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html.

I must be missing something. Any advice?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the ProvidePlugin?

Comment: @cgatian When I use the provide plugin, it will actually copy the full jquery lib into the bundle which references it. I already have jquery referenced in my application outside of webpack.

Comment: in first example, you still need to require it anywhere "Modules must be require()'d within in your bundle, or they will not be exposed."